# How to fetch all the publication targets in TOM.NET

Tags: event-system

Bundle is published to approved stage. and waiting for GracePeriod.
while publishing i need the below information related to the bundle
I want to get publication target of the bundle while moving from one workflow stage to another.

```
IList<PublishInfo> publishInfos = PublishEngine.GetPublishInfo(currentBundle).ToList();
                    foreach (PublishInfo pinfo in publishInfos)
                    {
                        string publicationTarget = pinfo.PublicationTarget.Title;
                    }
```

But i am empty in publishInfos.

Can any one help on this.

Comment: There's no publish info unless bundle is published already. I struggle to understand what exactly you need. Do you need to get the available publication targets for bundle (where it can be published), or do you need to get publication target your bundle is being published to right now?

Comment: I need to get publication target my bundle is being published to right now

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get publication target where item is being published right now you need to write event handler and subscribe to `PublishEventArgs`. This way you will get everything you need